# Display loading spinner during call when using fetch API

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch, loading, use-effect

how to create loading statement while it's fetching

```
useEffect(() => {

    fetch('https://hidden-shore-3231.herokuapp.com/allCarsHomePage')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setCards(data)
        })


}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating the loading spinner right before fetching, and then hiding / removing it after the promise is resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add a new state that is a boolean. When the endpoint is called update that state with `true`, and then when the data has been sent, and parsed, set the state back to `false`.

Meanwhile add a separate `return` that shows the spinner if the loading state is true.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function mockAPI() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    const json = JSON.stringify({"text": "Done!"});
    setTimeout(() => res(json), 3000);
  });
}

function Example() {

  const [ text, setText ] = useState('');
  const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function getData() {
      setIsLoading(true);
      mockAPI().then(json => {
        const data = JSON.parse(json);
        setText(data.text);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return 'Spinner';

  return (
    <div>{text}</div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```